# How do write this query correctly

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to execute this query in Sequelize but getting error

Query

```
LineItem.findAll(
        {
            attributes: [
                "orderId",
                [fn("sum", col("quantity")), "quantity"]
            ],
            include: [{
                model: Order,
                as: "lineItems",
                attributes: ["invoiceId"]
            }],
            group: ["orderId"],
            raw: true
        });
```

Error

```
column \"lineItems.invoice_id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant models to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, but first you must to answer this question: Do you need the column `invoiceId` in your query?

If your answer is YES, try it:

```js
LineItem.findAll({
  attributes: ['orderId', [fn('sum', col('quantity')), 'quantity']],
  include: [
    {
      model: Order,
      as: 'lineItems',
      attributes: ['invoiceId'],
    },
  ],
  group: ['orderId', 'invoiceId'],
  raw: true,
});
```

If your answer is NO, try it:

```js
LineItem.findAll({
  attributes: ['orderId', [fn('sum', col('quantity')), 'quantity']],
  include: [
    {
      model: Order,
      as: 'lineItems',
    },
  ],
  group: ['orderId'],
  raw: true,
});
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Yes I want invoiceId column, so I tried the first option, but it says column \"invoiceId\" does not exist

Comment: Can you send the script of tables and models? I need to understand your structure.